# Git subtree maximum function recursion depth

Tags: git, recursion, repository, git-subtree, subtree

After trying a `git subtree split -P foo/ -b "foo-branch"` command in my (pretty large) repository I get an error containing the following message:

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-subtree: 647: Maximum function recursion depth (1000) reached
```

The command works fine for my coworkers, which makes me think there is a problem with the configuration of my machine. The version of git I'm using is **2.30.2** on **Ubuntu 21.04**.
From my research I've found that this function recursion depth is hardcoded in the git source code, but most of the information is targeted at unrelated Python recursion functions (from what I know, git is written in C).

Is there a way to fix this? Can the git function recursion depth be in any way overridden?

Comment: It's a bug in the `git subtree` script, which relies on shell recursion. The limit isn't in Git: it's in /bin/sh.

Comment: Any tips on changing the /bin/sh limit? I did try changing the shell to bash and fish via `chsh -s`, didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like you found a different configuration or version of /bin/sh for your system, which got around the problem. Another way around it might be to edit the subtree script to invoke bash (make your own private subtree.bash version of the script, perhaps) but raising /bin/sh's recursion limit is probably better. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that the dash shell of Ubuntu 21.04 was the troublemaker.

After reconfiguring with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` and then selecting "No" the problem was fixed.